# AzureAD group objectid's matching LDAP attribute

Tags: ldap, azure-active-directory

I synchronized groups from AzureAD using LDAPS, and when using OpenId Connect, I get a claim with list of group `objectId`s the user is member of.
I originally thought that it'll match the group `ObjectGUID` attribute, but it doesn't.

How can I match the correct group to this objectId value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corresponding LDAP attribute is `msDS-AzureADObjectId`.
Can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/synchronization)